# Anr Message with synchronized method

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous

I get ANR when i try to get the data from the database

```
    public synchronized void  insertNewObstacle(Obstacle newObstacle) {

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            db.execSQL("Insert into "+OBSTACLES_TABLE+" Values ( ' "+
                    newObstacle.getLongitude()  + "' , ' " +
                    newObstacle.getLatitude()   + "' , ' " +
                    newObstacle.getDirection()  + "' , ' " +
                    newObstacle.getType()       + "' , ' " +
                    newObstacle.getAddress()    + "' , '" +
                    newObstacle.getSubmissionTime()     + "' , '" +
                    newObstacle.getSubmitterName() + "' )"
                    );

            db.close();

        }
```

The ANR happens because I'm getting the data from the server then save it locally
after saving it(Thread 1) i'm trying to get the saved data(Thread 2)  that's why i made
the method  synchronized.

My question is:

why it is not working and i'm getting that stupid ANR message?

or should i specify the order of accessing that method?

1.i have  asyncTaskLoader for getting the data from the server and saving it(Thread 1).

2.asyncTask for posting the data to the UI Thread(Thread 2).

Traces file:

```
at com.nilecode.matabat.AnonymousUser.DrawTypes(AnonymousUser.java:458)

at com.nilecode.matabat.AnonymousUser$MainNotificationReceiver.onReceive
(AnonymousUser.java:1085)

at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:763)

 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"AsyncTask #3" prio=5 tid=32 WAIT

| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xa57ed5e8 self=0xb8fcd4a0

| sysTid=2608 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1191480800

| state=S schedstat=( 21993697 71845945 80 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=0

at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0xa57ed700> 
(a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=32 (AsyncTask #3)

at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)

at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)

at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)

at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await
(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)

at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=29 WAIT

| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xa615bb08 self=0xb8e5b228

| sysTid=2578 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1192800808

| state=S schedstat=( 29573221 22137266 67 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=0

at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)

- waiting on <0xa60b1a28> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=29 (AsyncTask #2)

at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1205)

at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)

at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:159)

at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await
(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2019)

at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1013)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1073)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

"Binder_3" prio=5 tid=28 NATIVE

| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xa5144ba0 self=0xb8dd33e0

| sysTid=2574 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1194498544

| state=S schedstat=( 3711612 4635252 33 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
  #00  pc 0002cff4  
/system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+20)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"RenderDrive" prio=5 tid=27 SUSPENDED

 | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xa52ffd40 self=0xb8cf1eb0

| sysTid=2559 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1194081904

| state=S schedstat=( 278861639 194938487 3193 ) utm=0 stm=27 core=1
  #00  pc 0002ed67  
/system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall4+23)

at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)

at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1013)

at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:995)

at maps.p.b.c((null):-1)

at maps.an.b.run((null):-1)

"IntentService[Request New Dataset Service]" prio=5 tid=26 SUSPENDED

| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0xa60b9148 self=0xb8cce168

| sysTid=2557 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1194331408

| state=S schedstat=( 22023302408 4429908617 55349 ) utm=209 stm=1992 core=0
  #00  pc 0002ed67  
/system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall4+23)

at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)

at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:734)

at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)

at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)

at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)

at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1603)

at com.nilecode.matabat.data.LocalCachedObstacles.insertNewObstacle(LocalCachedObstacles.java:74)

at com.nilecode.matabat.data.LocalCachedObstacles.insertNewDataSet(LocalCachedObstacles.java:62)

at com.nilecode.matabat.ServerAsyncLoader.loadInBackground(ServerAsyncLoader.java:162)

at com.nilecode.matabat.RequestNewDataSetService.requestAndCacheNearByLocations
(RequestNewDataSetService.java:134)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`synchronized` method locks on the object itself. If another thread is holding that lock e.g. by running in some other synchronized method of the same object, your call will block until the lock is available.

Blocking the main UI thread for 5 secods or more causes the ANR.

Synchronization with sqlite is not necessary - the database will handle it own locking. However, an exclusive write transaction will prevent any other access with `SQLITE_BUSY` error.

Generally, sqlite works best if only one thread is accessing it. You should rethink your design. If there's a long-running database operation that does not need to be atomic, split it into shorter parts.

Answer (score 0):

ANR messages are shown when the UI thread is not responding more than 5 sec (varies with device). I think you're calling method from UI thread which is synchronised on the same object as the one on which you're calling `insertNewObstacle` method.

Also why are you using two separate threads for writing and reading ? Just use one `AsyncTask` which will fetch data from network and present data on UI thread in `doInBackground`.

Answer (score 0):

`ANR (Activity Not Responding)`  comes when ui tread wont receive any response for 5 seconds. Getting data from server the and saving it to data base can be done from background service with thread or only with service, why im suggesting background service so ui thread can run easily. And more over to load the data from the database i dont think u need async task.

Now why your getting ANR ?

so ans is your using two async tasks, both are ui thread blocker and one dependent on other. so unless you data not get loaded from the server and saved into database, your one more loading data to ui async task has to wait. so ui thread has to wait, utill it load the data from server and data to the ui. Async task has got different use case dont use it here and tru to avoid synchronization block unnessasary.