# why synchronized method in the sub thread hold the lock of main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a synchronized method. then I will start a Thread with long time operation,  the sub-thread also have a synchronized method, But the synchronized method in sub thread will hold the lock of the synchronized method which will cause anr in my appliction.

My code is:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class ThreadTest {

    static MQTTThread mThread;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("the  " + i + " -  restart time =  "
                    + new Date());
            restart(i);
        }
    }

    private static synchronized void restart(int i) {
        System.out.println("the " + i + " -  restart excute " + new Date());
        if (null != mThread) {
            if (!mThread.isAlive()) {
                try {
                    System.out
                    .println("Action:restartConnectThread in mThread.runFlag)");

                    mThread = new MQTTThread();
                    mThread.setName("MQTTThread");
                    mThread.start();
                    // mqttExecutor.execute(mThread);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("!mThread.runFlag");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Action:restartConnectThread - CONNECTING");
            }
        } else {
            try {
                System.out
                .println("Action:restartConnectThread in null thread");
                mThread = new MQTTThread();
                mThread.setName("MQTTThread");
                mThread.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("null mThread");
            }
        }
    }

    private static class MQTTThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {

            connectToServer();
            System.out.println("connected");
        }
    }

    public static synchronized void connectToServer() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Thread.sleep " + new Date());
            Thread.sleep(20000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Run the code  the result is :

Comment: Put it in your question. Not in the comments.

Comment: Can you write the original android code where you call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is standard behavior of synchronized methods.

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

> it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the
>   same object to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized
>   method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized
>   methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first
>   thread is done with the object.

So code

```
public synchronized void method() { 
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public void method() { 
    synchronized (this) {
    }
}
```

For your purposes you should use different lock-objects for `connectToServer` and `restart` methods

UPD. Sorry, I missed, that your methods are static. In this case [specification 8.4.3.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6)

> A synchronized method acquires a monitor before it executes.
>   For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class object for the method's class is used.

So you can not run two synchronized methods of a class simultaneously, even if they are static

Answer (score 0):

> Blocking the main UI thread for 5 secods or more causes the ANR.

from [Anr Message with synchronized method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996346/anr-message-with-synchronized-method)

Maybe that's happening because of:

```
Thread.sleep(20000);
```

Avoid to lock the main UI thread.